# Specifying the file path to the setBitmap() method in a pos printer

Tags: java, image

I'm trying to print an image using the following code to a pos printer.

```
String spath = "E:\\javapos\\javapos.bmp";
System.out.println("***************" + spath);
ptr.setBitmap(1, POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, spath,
                 (ptr.getRecLineWidth() / 2),
                 POSPrinterConst.PTR_BM_CENTER);
```

This works fine in the IDE, but when I compile it to the jar it gives me an error.
The error is as follows,

```
jpos.JposException: Could not create an image object with JAI.
    at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService.setMemoryImage(CommonPrinterService.java:7506) at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService.setBitmap(aCommonPrinterService.java:6611)  at jpos.POSPrinter.setBitmap(Unknown Source)
    at possystem.MainInterface.initPrinter(MainInterface.java:2354)
    at possystem.MainInterface.checkOut(MainInterface.java:1960)
    at possystem.MainInterface.jTextField23KeyPressed(MainInterface.java:175
```

Any help is thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: What's the type of the variable `ptr`?

Comment: Its pointing to a PosPrinter object. `POSPrinterControl114 ptr = (POSPrinterControl114) new POSPrinter();`

Comment: Do you have the source code of the class?

Comment: No, I only have the compiled code. [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f879528d96b0d2133a17)

Comment: Try with IntelliJ IDEA's decompiler. Its output is much more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the issue. The issue was not with the path but me not having installed JAI for my Java Run Time engine. I installed  JAI for my JRE and now it works fine.
Thanks everyone for the help.